# How to hide the form parameters from url after submitting a form

Tags: java, struts2

After submitting a form, calling an action and redirecting to show the jsp, the final url of the browser will show the action with the submit parameters as follows.  Is it possible to hide the parameters ?

```
http://localhost:8080/myproject/login?username=aaa&password=123
```

Comment: Show your action configuration.

Comment: Chage to post. But it is same...

Comment: I guess this is what you need - Submit form via POST and then redirect using 302 (redirect or redirectAction struts2-result)

Answer (score 0):

Use "redirect" result type to send the redirect to the browser. The parameters should still be in your session/action context.

Comment: The `redirectAction` probably fits better.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @sanbhat is right - use a POST request so that the parameters do not appear in the URL. Using browser dev tools or similar it's still possible to inspect the request and it's post data, there's nothing you can do about that.

In the final redirect to the result JSP, (which presumably shows what the user wrote on the form), then the fields can be populated by saving the results in session scope, so no need to have request parameters on the redirect URL.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are making a GET call here..

in the submit action make sure you specify method="post" so that password wont appear as parameter

Answer (score 0):

You are using `get` method. Change it to `post` method. Example is:

form method="post" name="form name" action="Your action page"

Answer (score 0):

use post method in the form , default is get so u always see the parameters in the url.
**`<form action="some.jsp" method="post">`**